# Javascript String Splitting

Tags: javascript, regex

So if I have a string like:

`'boss: "Person 1" AND occupation: "Engineer"'`

Is there a way I can split the string into an array like such:

`['boss:', '"Person 1"', 'AND', 'occupation:', '"Engineer"']`

I have lots of different regex splits and multiple argument splits and I can't seem to achieve this. Any ideas?

FYI: yes I would like to leave in the quotations surrounding Person 1 and Engineer and maintain the spaces in whatever is between quotations

Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var input = 'boss: "Person 1" AND occupation: "Engineer"';

console.log(input.match(/"[^"]*"|[^ ]+/g));

// Output:
// [ 'boss:', '"Person 1"', 'AND', 'occupation:', '"Engineer"' ]
```

**Explanation**

You want to match two kinds of things:

1. Things without spaces in them (since spaces separate terms).
2. Things in quotes (where spaces are allowed).

The regular expression here consists of two parts:

1. `"[^"]*"` - This matches a double quote, followed by any number of non-double-quote characters, followed by another double quote.
2. `[^ ]+` - This matches one or more non-space characters.

The two are combined with a pipe (`|`), which means "or." Together, they match both types of things you want to find.

Comment: Another answer here pointed out that the first part of the regular expression could be `".*?"` instead. I think that's perfectly fine too.

Answer (score 0):

If `console.log` prints an array, it surrounds each string  element with
apostrophes, so you see the apostrophes only in console output.

If you want to get a **string** formatted the way you want,
use the following script:

```
var str = 'boss: "Person 1" AND occupation: "Engineer"';
var pat = /"[^"]+"|\S+/g;
var res1 = str.match(pat);
var result = "['" + res1.join("', '") + "']";
```